# Python regex for UK number

Tags: python, regex

Below given are the UK phone numbers need to fetch from text file:

```
07791523634 
07910221698
```

But it only print `0779152363`, `0791022169` skipping the 11th character.

Also it produce unnecessary values like ('')
            Ex : `'', '07800 854536'`
Below is the regex I've used:

```
phnsrch = re.compile(r'\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{5}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{5}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}|/^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$/|')
```

Need help to fetch the complete set of 11 numbers without any unnecessary symbols

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: If the phone number were in simple form, `07\d{9}` would suffice, so I'm guessing you have some complex input with dashes and the like. Please give example input if this is necessary for your lookup.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on how many special cases you want to handle.  Dashes allowed?  Dots?  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the solution for matching the UK numbers below:

```
07540858798
0113 2644489
02074 735 217
07512 850433
01942 896007
01915222200
01582 492734
07548 021 475
020 8563 7296
07791523634
```

```
re.compile(r'\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{5}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4})')
```

Thanks to those who helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is too long and can be more easier, try this regex instead:

```
^(07\d{8,12}|447\d{7,11})$
```